# Not able to send email using office 365 getting error Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: node.js, office365, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer to send the email. I have tried with gmail account its working fine. but using office 365 I am getting error like  Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful.

This is my code.

```
const nodeMailer = require("nodemailer");

    exports.sendEmail = async emailData => {
      const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.outlook365.com",
        service: "outlook",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        requireTLS: true,
        auth: {
          user: "vijay@******.com",
          pass: "As?***************"
        },
        tls: {
          ciphers: "SSLv3",
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
      });

      return transporter
        .sendMail(emailData)
        .then(info => console.log(`Message sent: ${info.response}`))
        .catch(err => console.log(`Problem sending email: ${err}`));
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late answer but it can help someone.

If wrote the password correctly and it didn't work, this can be because of two reasons:

1. You two step authentication, and nodejs doesn't support that. But this can be solved by genrating a app password and using it instead of regular one.
2. If you are using office for bussiness and you are admin you need to disable, security default see [this](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1071) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/concept-fundamentals-security-defaults) for more information.

If you don't want  or can't do the things stated above. There are alternatives, you can just use Outlook Graph API to send the mails.